# Who was the first comic book hero to have a bullet proof uniform?

Tags: comics, history-of, super-hero

Who was the first comic book hero to have a bullet proof uniform?

Comment: Its scope is too broad. So, its off-topic here. See FAQ of the site..

Comment: @SachinShekhar, it seems on topic to me.  Comics involving bulletproof uniforms would generally be science fiction or fantasy, and it has a definite answer.  (I've no idea what it is, but it has one.)

Comment: @cjm The hit point isn't that. Its scope is too broad, that's why its off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Godlike beings like Enki (6000 BC) and Superman (1938) can use their aura to protect things close to them:

[image: Supes]

But more human superheroes like [Batman (1939)](https://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batsuit) and [Phoenix Jones (2010)](https://abcnews.go.com/US/real-life-seattle-superhero-phoenix-jones-suffers-broken/story?id=12589895#.UE8Z-5aQFGE) simply use [ballistic vests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_vest). As far as I know, **Batman** was the first comic book hero with a bulletproof uniform, but there may be earlier ones, like [The Phantom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom) (1936).

[image: The Batman]
[image: The Phantom]

Comment: In [Smallville](http://smallville.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Suit), Supes' suit is bulletproof.

Comment: Why the downvote? Should i quote the "suit is bulletproof" sentence from the Batman article?